# how two orderBy item names alphabetically, grouping those that start with a letter and then those that start with a number using typeORM

Tags: typescript, database, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

In a NestJS project using typeORM, I'm trying to sort the return of names from a repository alphabetically, but the result is either [0-9][A-Z] in ASC, or [Z-A][9-0] in DESC. What I need is to reverse the grouping so that the results is [A-Z][0-9].

Our database uses Postgres and my attempts have led me to the following:

```
sellablesRespQuery
   .addOrderBy('sellable.name', 'ASC')
   .addOrderBy('case when sellable.name ~ \'^[a-zA-Z]\' then 1 else 0 end', 'ASC');
```

But this generates the following error:

```
TypeORMError: "case when sellable" alias was not found. Maybe you forgot to join it?
```

Evidently, I'm not making myself clear to typeORM. Can anyone please help?

Comment: add `loggin: ['query']` in your typeorm config to see the query generated by typeorm

Comment: Yes, thank you for that. I'm still working on the problem, but still haven't found a solution.

The following code
```
sellablesRespQuery.addOrderBy(
          "(case when name ~ \\'^[A-Za-z]\\' then 1 else 0 end)"
        );
```

...generates the following SQL...

```
ORDER BY (case when name ~ \'^[A-Za-z]\' then 1 else 0 end) ASC
```

...which produces the following error...

```
error: syntax error at or near ","
```

My assumption is I need to remove the `ASC` but I've been unable to figure it out.